# Creating a skew box shadow on DIV

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do i add a skew box shadow on a div element?

[image]

I've tried adding an absolute div behind the div but this doesn't seem to work correctly.

The css i tried is:

```
.shadow-box-bg {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
width: 150px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 9;
-webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
-moz-transform: skew(20deg);
-o-transform: skew(20deg);
transform: scale(2.3) rotate(88deg) translateX(67px) translateY(-17px) skewX(3deg) skewY(-2deg);
```

}

It seems as though i could have better luck using a div shadow. But i have no idea how to make it skew.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use pseudoelements instead of creating empty div for styling purpose only

e.g.  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNQjgB

---

**Markup**

```
<div class="skewedshadow"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
   width: 200px;
   height: 400px;
   background: #b33049;
}

.skewedshadow {
  position: relative;
}

.skewedshadow:before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background: rgba(0,0,0, .45);  
  transform: rotate(1.5deg) translateX(10px) translateY(15px) skewX(4deg) skewY(-4deg);
}
```

---

**Result**

[image]